# C warning with char array: "warning: array subscript has type 'char'"

Tags: c, arrays, types, char, warnings

I am confused as to why this error occurs.
My code execute fine and the results is exactly what I want but on compiling my c file with the command: 
"gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o assignment2 assignment2.c"

Here is the code:

[image]

Here is the output error:

[image]

I would just use this but i'm sure it might have some reasons why an error shows and also because my assignment marker probably want accept it if there is this warning on compilation.

Comment: Why is `i` a `char`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `i` for a counter, use `int` instead of `char`

```
int i = 0;
```

this will fix the problem.

But also, `c` should be an `int`, because `fgetc()` can return `EOF` which is an `int`, and in general the return type of `fgetc()` is `int`, thus you should use `int` for `c` too.

Your code should be then

```
char word[500];
int i = 0;
int c;

while (((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
    word[i++] = (char) c;
}
word[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: @KeineLust, the code had Undefined Behavior, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Oh man, I was trying this and that from other answers online and ended up missing this little mistake. Thanks a lot for pointing that out for me.

Comment: @jjyj That's what *Stack Overflow* is for, and it's fun to help. But keep in mind, that you should post actual code instead of images next time.

Answer (score -2):

`i` should be evaluated so that `i < 500` is fullfilled